# Auto post things from my website to Facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I set up a cron job on my website a while ago (in November specifically), that posts updates to my Facebook page (fan page) every night. Everything was working fine until a few days ago, when I noticed that normal visitors were not able to see the posts from 12th of January onwards.

But I (a page owner) could see these new posts. I thought that it was something to do with the access token expiration. So I renewed it and tried to auto post again.

And it does the same thing still - I can see the posts when I'm logged in as a page owner, however if I visit the Facebook page as a guest, last post I can see is from 12th of January.

One thing I noticed is that on the posts, where it says 'Published by ..', it used to say my name (so for all the posts that are visible to the guests, it says my name under Published by), but the ones that don't show up, have my page's name, which is exactly the same as the name of the app I created specifically for this.

I know it's a long shot probably, but perhaps someone out there has had the similar issue?

Comment: That's it! It was put 'in development' mode for some reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WizKid's hint led me to find out that the app was put in development mode for some reason.

I made it public again and now it works!